# animation on a backbone view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

How to make my backbone slide - some animation on a Backbone view

```
 var View = Backbone.View.extend({

  el : "#editor",               // Bind to the editor id

  render : function() {

     var data = {
       item: this.model,
       _: _ 
     };

     var compiledTemplate = _.template( Template, data ); // Merge model with template
     this.$el.html( compiledTemplate );
     this.$('.editor-pane').show(500);       // Does animation work here...NO!! Urgh. 
     return this;
  } 
 });
```

Yes. #editor contains .editor-pane

Im also happy with a version on the #editor element:

```
     this.$el.html( compiledTemplate ).show ('slow');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to move animation in another method and run it after render. Also I advise to use jQuery 'find' method to browse DOM.

```
initialize: function(){
    ...
    this.render();
    this.animateView();
}

animateView: function(){
    this.$el.find('.editor-pane').show(500);
}
```

Comment: would it be possible to fire a events {'onload